# integrate $\int_D e^{x^2+3y^2}$

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, multiple-integral

Evaluate $\int_D e^{x^2+3y^2}$, where $D$ is the region bounded in the first quadrant by the lines $y=0, y=x, x^2+3y^2=1$.

My method is as follows, and I am not sure if it is correct.

Let $u=x, v=\sqrt{3}y$. Then $D$ becomes bounded by $v=0, \frac{\sqrt{3}}{3}v=u, u^2+v^2=1$.

$u=r\cos\theta, v=r\sin\theta$, so $\int_D e^{x^2+3y^2} = \int_D e^{r^2}r = \int^{\pi/6}_0e^{r^2}r$

Is this correct? If not, can you tell me where I got this wrong? Thank you.

Comment: You need to include the Jacobian when transforming from (x,y) to (u,v),and when transforming from the latter to polar coordinates, the Jacobian is r, but you then have an integral over theta and r, the integral over r is missing (and it's conventional to indicate the integration variables, say x and y, by dxdy)

Comment: so you are saying I just need one more Jacobian?

Comment: Do it step by step, start with computing the Jacobian from (x,y) to (u,v)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $u=x$ and $v=\sqrt{3}y$. 
Then the three constraints become $v=0$, $v=\sqrt{3}u$, and $u^2+v^2=1$. Using the equations $x=u$ and $y=\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}v$, 
we obtain the absolute value of the Jacobian to be: 
\begin{align*}
\Bigg| \frac{\partial(x,y)}{\partial(u,v)} \Bigg| &= 
\Bigg| 
\det
\begin{pmatrix}
x_u & x_v \\ 
y_u & y_v \\ 
\end{pmatrix}
\Bigg| 
= \Bigg| 
\det
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 \\ 
0 & \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}} \\ 
\end{pmatrix}
\Bigg|  
= \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}. 
\end{align*}
So we have 
\begin{align*}
\iint_{D} e^{x^2+3y^2}dA  
&= \int_{0}^{\frac{1}{2}}\int_{y}^{\sqrt{1-3y^2}} e^{x^2+3y^2}dxdy \\
&= \int_{0}^{\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}}\int_{\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}v}^{\sqrt{1-v^2}} e^{u^2+v^2}\Bigg| \frac{\partial(x,y)}{\partial(u,v)} \Bigg|dudv \\ 
&= \int_{0}^{\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}}\int_{\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}v}^{\sqrt{1-v^2}} e^{u^2+v^2}\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}} dudv \\ 
&= \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}} \int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{3}} \int_{0}^{1} e^{r^2} r drd\theta \hspace{4mm}\mbox{ since } u = r \cos \theta\mbox{ and }v = r\sin \theta \\ 
&= \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}\frac{\pi}{3}   \frac{1}{2}\int_{0}^{1} e^{w} dw \hspace{4mm}\mbox{ since } w=r^2, \mbox{ so }  dw = 2rdr  \\
&=\frac{\pi}{6\sqrt{3}}(e-1). 
\end{align*}